# Getting System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException in Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm get a System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException occasionally after publishing code to our production servers.  This logs in the server event log and returns a 500 to the client making the request.

> Fixing it requires stopping IIS, clearing the .NET temporary files and
>   then restarting IIS.

My question is that, short of watching the web traffic with Fiddler and monitoring the server event logs, how can I trap this exception.
I have an error handler in the svc file that catches some errors, but this seems to happen outside of the actual service code.  I'd like to be able to catch it an get notifications.

The full text of the exception is as follows:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/63835064
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/SCORMInterface.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_yuna0pfp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_yuna0pfp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
Process Name: w3wp
```

Comment: Instead of trapping it, how about finding out what the problem is, and fixing it?

Comment: There is no problem.  Once I've cleared the temp files and restarted IIS everything works fine.  It's just occasionally when we publish, it gets into this state, I'd like some way to get notified that it has.

Comment: The fact that it gets into this state is a problem. It's not supposed to "get into this state".